# Can error in WINAPI call halt the execution of code in BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, backgroundworker

My application lists all the file extensions with their default icon. On start of the application I use BackgroundWorker to get all the file extensions and their associated icons. Some user reported that the application infinitely shows loading screen with no crash or exception. So I removed the part that get the icons associated with file extensions and everything works fine for them.

Here is code for BackgroundWorker.

```
var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
var progressDialog = new ProgressDialog();
backgroundWorker.DoWork += (o, args) =>
{
    FileExtension.GetFileExtensions();
    GetImages();
};
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, args) =>
{
    Toggle();
    progressDialog.Close();
};
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
progressDialog.ShowDialog();
```

But I like to know I uses following code to get the image. Does error in WINAPI call can halt the execution of BackgroundWorker?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
struct SHFILEINFO
{
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public int iIcon;
    public uint dwAttributes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string szDisplayName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
    public string szTypeName;
}


[Flags]
enum FileInfoFlags
{
    ShgfiIcon = 0x000000100,
    ShgfiUsefileattributes = 0x000000010
}

[DllImport("Shell32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
extern static IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(
    string pszPath,
    int dwFileAttributes,
    out SHFILEINFO psfi,
    int cbFileInfo,
    FileInfoFlags uFlags);
public enum IconSize
{
    Large = 0x000000000,
    Small = 0x000000001
}

public static Image GetImageExtension(string fileExt, IconSize size)
{
    var fileInfo = new SHFILEINFO();
    SHGetFileInfo(fileExt, 0, out fileInfo, Marshal.SizeOf(fileInfo),
        FileInfoFlags.ShgfiIcon | FileInfoFlags.ShgfiUsefileattributes | (FileInfoFlags)size);
    try
    {
        return Icon.FromHandle(fileInfo.hIcon).ToBitmap();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Resources.picture_16;
    }
}

private static string TrimMatchingQuotes(this string input, char quote)
{
    if ((input.Length >= 2) &&
        (input[0] == quote) && (input[input.Length - 1] == quote))
        return input.Substring(1, input.Length - 2);

    return input;
}

private static Icon ExtractIcon(string file, int number, bool largeIcon)
{
    IntPtr large;
    IntPtr small;
    ExtractIconEx(file, number, out large, out small, 1);
    try
    {
        return Icon.FromHandle(largeIcon ? large : small);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }

}

[DllImport("Shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "ExtractIconExW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern int ExtractIconEx(string sFile, int iIndex, out IntPtr piLargeVersion, out IntPtr piSmallVersion, int amountIcons);

[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr ExtractAssociatedIcon(IntPtr hInst, StringBuilder lpIconPath,
   out ushort lpiIcon);

public static Image GetImage(string icon)
{
    try
    {
        if (icon.Contains(","))
        {
            var split = icon.Split(new[] { ',' });
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(split[0]))
            {
                int index;
                int.TryParse(split[1], out index);
                var image =
                    ExtractIcon(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(split[0]).TrimMatchingQuotes('\"'),
                                index, false);
                if (image != null)
                    return image.ToBitmap();
            }
        }
        if (File.Exists(icon))
        {
            try
            {
                var image = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(icon);
                return image != null ? image.ToBitmap() : Resources.picture_16;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                var strB = new StringBuilder(icon);
                ushort uicon;
                var handle = ExtractAssociatedIcon(IntPtr.Zero, strB, out uicon);
                return Icon.FromHandle(handle).ToBitmap();
            }
        }
        return Resources.picture_16;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Resources.picture_16;
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt the root cause is not in WINAPI, is in how bgw is used, so post the code pf bgw?

Comment: Probably unrelated but you need to `DestroyIcon()` the handle from `SHGetFileInfo/ExtractIconEx`

Comment: Posted BackgroundWorker code. In GetImages I use foreach to cycle through each file extension in list and using functions I stated above to get images for ImageList. I removed GetImages function from DoWork and that done the trick so I'm suspicious about WinAPI code.

Comment: If this only happens for one user, then check what Shell Extensions that user has installed. You may find they have something for managing icons or similar. As a guide, if an issue only affects one person, work out what is different for that person compared to everyone else.